# How to install opencl in CentOS 7 using yum?

Tags: centos, apt, yum, imagemagick

I need to install opencl in CentOS 7 nvidia. I already installed cuda. But when I try to install ImageMagick with OpenCL, it is showing `CL/cl.h not found`. But there are files in

```
/usr/local/cuda-7.5/include/CL
```

How to resolve it? Whether OpenCL is installed or not? If it is not installed means how to install it?

I know how to install in Ubuntu.

> http://arrayfire.com/opencl-on-intel-hd-iris-graphics-on-linux/

But how to use apt-get in CentOS.

I followed the link

> http://everyday-tech.com/apt-get-on-centos/

While doing

```
yum install apt
```

it is showing

> No package apt available.

So apt-get command instruction steps are not the same in CentOS.

Can someone help me with the installation process using `yum`?

Comment: Your link is about an apt repo (apt for rpm) at RPMFORGE http://mirror.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/mirror/dag/redhat/el7/en/x86_64/rpmforge/RPMS/ ... with 245 packages , no openCL. ...

Comment: ? Have you checked that the headers are present in `/usr/local/cuda-7.5/include/CL/` ?

Comment: If you're on CentOs you want to be using `yum`, not `apt`. Try using `yum search` and see what packages you can find (e.g. *yum search opencl\** or *yum search ImageMagick\**).

Answer (score 5):

I found this helpful for installing OpenCL: https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=63270#p266493

Which led me to run:

```
$ yum install opencl-headers
$ yum provides '*/libOpenCL.so'
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper 
epel                                                                                                                                                                              
...
ocl-icd-devel-2.2.12-1.el6.i686 : Development files for ocl-icd
Repo        : epel
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib/libOpenCL.so



ocl-icd-devel-2.2.12-1.el6.x86_64 : Development files for ocl-icd
Repo        : epel
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libOpenCL.so
```

and thus:

```
$ sudo yum install ocl-icd
```

There remains an issue in which you may need to symlink whatever libOpenCL.so you install to /usr/lib/ I think? I was able to solve my installation problem after I ran:

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libOpenCL.so.1 /usr/lib/libOpenCL.so
```

Comment: You're a life-saver man !! Thanks a ton

Answer (score 2):

The cuda opencl should be OK, I think.

Configuring ImageMagick, please try ...

```
./configure CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/cuda-7.5/include/CL
```

Comment: Sorry I am not able to comment @Knud Larsen. It is working. Thank u so much. But still it is showing > checking CL/cl.h usability... yes > checking CL/cl.h presence... no > configure: WARNING: CL/cl.h: accepted by compiler, rejected by the preprocessor! >configure: WARNING: CL/cl.h: proceeding with the compiler's result >checking for CL/cl.h... yes What does this mean? Will it work or not?

Comment: @user177257 If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites. If you have another question, pelase ask it separately.

Answer (score 2):

Enable [epel 7 repo](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL#How_can_I_use_these_extra_packages.3F) and

```
yum install opencl-headers
```

About apt from rpmforge is [apt-rpm](http://apt-rpm.org) which be able to install rpms from apt repos and haven't much success. I don't see how that could be useful for you .

The apt-get , as debian do , exist in my [copr](https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/sergiomb/debs/) for example ,
but apt install  won't work because apt database haven't any package , and you will have unmet dependencies ... and more reasons